# UTC support for comparing 2 files date/time

Tags: delphi, date, time, utc

I have a utility that compares a source and destination file date/time.  This works in most cases but fails when comparing date/time for files in different time zones.  So I need a UTC datetime routine.

From looking around it seems the Windows API GetFileTime will support this.  I also found this wrapper procedure, but it crashes on the GetFileTime call when compiled under Delphi 2010.

Any ideas?  Or does anyone have a snippet of code that handles UTC timezones etc that I can pass 2 filenames to that will tell me if they are different?

```
function CompareFileTimes(File1, File2 : String) : LongInt;
var
  F1, F2          : THandle;
  F1_CreateTime,
  F1_LastAccess,
  F1_LastWrite,
  F2_CreateTime,
  F2_LastAccess,
  F2_LastWrite    : PFileTime;
begin
  //Initialize all variables
  F1 := 0;
  F2 := 0;

  //Since these are pointers, we have to
  //allocate memory for the FileTime structures
  GetMem(F1_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  GetMem(F1_LastAccess, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  GetMem(F1_LastWrite, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  GetMem(F2_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  GetMem(F2_LastAccess, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  GetMem(F2_LastWrite, SizeOf(TFileTime));

  //Fill the structures with nulls for now
  FillChar(F1_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime), #0);
  FillChar(F1_LastAccess, SizeOf(TFileTime), #0);
  FillChar(F1_LastWrite, SizeOf(TFileTime), #0);
  FillChar(F2_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime), #0);
  FillChar(F2_LastAccess, SizeOf(TFileTime), #0);
  FillChar(F2_LastWrite, SizeOf(TFileTime), #0);

  //Get file handles for the files in question
  //Notice that even though we're using CreateFile
  //the open disposition for the file is OPEN_EXISTING
  F1 := CreateFile(PChar(F1), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  F2 := CreateFile(PChar(F2), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

  //Get the file times for the files.
  GetFileTime(F1, F1_CreateTime, F1_LastAccess, F1_LastWrite);
  GetFileTime(F2, F2_CreateTime, F2_LastAccess, F2_LastWrite);

  //Assign the function's result to comparison
  //-1, File1 is younger than File2
  //0, File1 is the same as File2
  //+1 File1 is older than File2
  Result := CompareFileTime(F1_CreateTime^, F2_CreateTime^);

  //Free the memory allocated to the pointers
  FreeMem(F1_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  FreeMem(F1_LastAccess, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  FreeMem(F1_LastWrite, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  FreeMem(F2_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  FreeMem(F2_LastAccess, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  FreeMem(F2_LastWrite, SizeOf(TFileTime));
end;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Declare TFileTime variables instead of PFileTime variables, and you do not have to GetMem and FreeMem (but of course FillChar).

Comment: Changing the declaration to TFileTime then gives a compile error on the CreateFile calls because it is expecting PFileTime.

Comment: @TallGuy: use the address operator "@" to pass in a pointer, e.g.  `GetFileTime(F1, @F1_CreateTime, @F1_LastAccess, @F1_LastWrite);`

Comment: Thanks, it now compiles, but doesn't give the correct result.  ie 2 files with obviously different dates give the same date as a result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How is all that code relevant to your question about UTC file times? It looks like you really wanted to ask *two separate questions*. One was supposed to be about whether files in two different time zones have the same time, and the other was supposed to be about what's wrong with that code. Please edit this one to remove the irrelevant part and post it in a new question.

Comment: @Andreas: ZeroMemory would be a better choice than FillChar? FillChar's byte centered operation was only preserved into D2009+ because of the way it was mostly used. Very nice, but also unfortunate as we now have a "...Char..." function that operates on bytes instead of Chars.

Comment: @TallGuy. Looks like the main remaining error would be `...CreateFile(PChar(F1), 0...` instead of `CreateFile(PChar(File1), 0`. See my answer for a (hopefully) correct version.  And it's **always** a good habit to check for error after using API routines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi 2010 already contains an easy wrapper for getting the UTC time in ioutils.pas. Here is a piece of code that compares UTC creation times of files.

```
uses
  IOUtils, DateUtils;

function CompareFileCreationTimeUtc(const aFile1, aFile2: String): integer;
var
  lCreationTime1: TDateTime;
  lCreationTime2: TDateTime;
begin

  lCreationTime1 := TFile.GetCreationTimeUtc(aFile1);
  lCreationTime2 := TFile.GetCreationTimeUtc(aFile2);

  Result := CompareDateTime(lCreationTime1, lCreationTime2);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use IOUtils routine and like to do it yourself, your function should be corrected like (untested):

```
function CompareFileTimes(File1, File2 : String) : LongInt;
var
  F1, F2: THandle;
  F1_CreateTime, F2_CreateTime: TFileTime;
begin
  //Fill the structures with nulls for now
  ZeroMemory(@F1_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime));
  ZeroMemory(@F2_CreateTime, SizeOf(TFileTime));

  //Get file handles for the files in question
  //Notice that even though we're using CreateFile
  //the open disposition for the file is OPEN_EXISTING
  F1 := CreateFile(PChar(File1), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ , nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  F2 := CreateFile(PChar(File2), 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

  if (F1=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) or (F1=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    RaiseLastOSError;

  //Get the file times for the files.
  if not GetFileTime(F1, @F1_CreateTime, nil, nil) or
     not GetFileTime(F2, @F2_CreateTime, nil, nil) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  //Assign the function's result to comparison
  //-1, File1 is younger than File2
  //0, File1 is the same as File2
  //+1 File1 is older than File2
  Result := CompareFileTime(F1_CreateTime, F2_CreateTime);
end;
```